# How do I import classes from a different package that is located in a different folder?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have 2 folders in my project, A and B. A contains the classes I want access to but the classes in there are part of their own package. In folder B, I have a similar setup but I need to call the classes in folder A. I tried regular import statements but that didn't work. The 2 packages are in completely separate folders, each with their own settings. They're 2 seperate springboot applications and I'm trying to get them to work with each other. How would I do this?

This is what I'm talking about:

```
package A;
import classes;

public class Controller{
    //methods I need
}
```

What I tried was:

```
package B;
import classes from B;
import packageA.classesfromA;

public class ControllerB{
    //methods
}
```

Screenshots:[import error from B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJQQ6.png),
[the 2 folders that contain what I need, B is partyinthebackend, cs320EthicsPlayer is A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fB79.png)

Comment: Q: Could you provide an example with legal Java syntax, and copy/paste the specific error text?  And please consider switching to a more Java-friendly IDE, like Eclipse, Netbeans or IntelliJ.

Comment: A dot '.' within the to be imported package-term represents a directory separator, maybe that info helps you.